# How can I make a git hook to update the npm patch version on every commit or merge to master?

Tags: git, npm, versioning, semantic-versioning

### TLDR version of my question:

What I want is that doing work and committing things to feature branches (anything non-master) doesn't touch the version number, but committing or merging into `master` does. The version number is in `package.json`.

What should the setup for this look like?

### The long version (what I've tried)

In trying to automate version numbers, I've found that doing `npm version patch` will bump the version in the `package.json` file, which is one part of what I'm trying to do. And then playing with the sample hooks in git's `.git/hooks` directory, I found that they are just shell scripts that fire on various events, which is great, and they are the second part of what I'm trying to do.

But I can't figure out how to connect them.

Obstacle number 1 is that `npm version patch` seems to want to do a commit and a tag, and so doing it together with the work that I'm already committing (as a `pre-commit` hook) fails with an error message saying "Git working directory not clean".

What I want is that it just *also* bumps the version along all of the changes that I'm already committing (or merging), instead of creating a brand new commit and a tag, so that I avoid having my commit history being plagued by commit messages that are just the version number on every other commit.

Obstacle number 2 is very simply that the `pre-merge-commit` hook doesn't seem to fire. I've tested the `pre-commit` hook by just echoing a message and then exiting with `1`, which works; But as a `pre-merge-commit` (and then doing a `merge`), the merge just succeeds without my hook stopping it.

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to connect these two things to work with each other.